# Hidden Markov Model and Viterbi algorithm: Understanding the Casino Problem?

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, machine-learning, bayesian-network

I am deeply struggling with understanding how to apply the Viterbi algorithm. From my course notes, I have the following simple(I'm told) example:

[image]

> If the sequence `HH` was observed, what is the most likely sequence in
>   which Fair and Biased coins were used ?

Following table was generated as part of solution:

[image]

and the answer was given as **O-Biased-Fair** with probability **0.2025**.

Can someone explain this answer in much detail and simplest way possible ? Thanks.

Comment: To be clear:  moving from one coin to another is probabilistic, and that selection is independent of how the toss comes out?  If so, I don't understand the values.

Comment: Yes. If the values you refer to are from the table, that is what I am trying to understand.

Comment: Well, I don't understand those values.  What do $0$ and $1$ mean in that table?  What do you mean by writing $O-Biased-Fair$ (as opposed to, say, simply "$Biased-Fair$")?

Comment: The 0 and 1 are base cases for the Viberti algorithm which considers recursively decreasing values. Here is the link to the full note: http://www.cs.hunter.cuny.edu/~saad/courses/bayes/notes/note11.pdf

Comment: The O as I understand is the original state before any observations were made.

Comment: Yes...and I suppose the writer imagines that we leave that state according to the toss of an unbiased coin.  I see the "absolute" probability of the $Biased-Fair$ combination as $.405$, twice the value you have...I suppose reflecting the fact that you only start with $B$ half the time.  Still, the other numbers look odd.  I'll write something up and post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table has values
$$
\begin{array}{lc|lcrr}
& & & \text{H} & \text{H} & \qquad\text{($X_i$ values)} \\
\hline
& 0 & \nu_1(0) & \nu_2(0) & \nu_3(0) & \\
\text{($\pi_i$ values)} & F & \nu_1(F) & \nu_2(F) & \nu_3(F) & \\
& B & \nu_1(B) & \nu_2(B) & \nu_3(B) &
\end{array}
$$

where $\nu_i(j),\; i\in\{1,2,3\},\; j\in\{0,F,B\}$ are defined in your notes.

We are given:

\begin{align}
P(\pi_1=0) &= 1 \\
P(\pi_2=F\mid \pi_1=0) &= 0.5 \\
P(\pi_2=B\mid \pi_1=0) &= 0.5 \\
\text{for $n\geq 3$}\qquad P(\pi_n=F\mid \pi_{n-1}=F) &= 0.9 \\
P(\pi_n=B\mid \pi_{n-1}=F) &= 0.1 \\
P(\pi_n=F\mid \pi_{n-1}=B) &= 0.9 \\
P(\pi_n=B\mid \pi_{n-1}=B) &= 0.1 \\
& \\
P(X_1=\text{null}\mid \pi_1=0) &= 1 \\
\text{for $n\geq 2$}\qquad P(X_n=H\mid \pi_n=F) &= 0.5 \\
P(X_n=T\mid \pi_n=F) &= 0.5 \\
P(X_n=H\mid \pi_n=B) &= 0.9 \\
P(X_n=T\mid \pi_n=B) &= 0.1.
\end{align}

We now calculate the $\nu_i(j)$ values recursively.

\begin{align}
\nu_1(0) &= P(X_1=\text{null}\mid \pi_1=0)P(\pi_1=0) \\
&= 1\times 1 = 1 \\
\nu_1(F) &= P(X_1=\text{null}\mid \pi_1=F)P(\pi_1=F) = 0 \qquad\text{since $P(\pi_1=F) = 0$} \\
\nu_1(B) &= P(X_1=\text{null}\mid \pi_1=B)P(\pi_1=B) = 0 \qquad\text{since $P(\pi_1=B) = 0$}.
\end{align}

These three values form column $1$ of the result table.

\begin{align}
& \\
\nu_2(0) &= P(X_2=H\mid \pi_2=0)\max_{l\in\{0,F,B\}} \{\nu_1(l)P(\pi_2=0\mid\pi_1=l)\} \\
&= 0 \\
& \\
\nu_2(F) &= P(X_2=H\mid \pi_2=F)\max_{l\in\{0,F,B\}} \{\nu_1(l)P(\pi_2=F\mid\pi_1=l)\} \\
&= 0.5\times (1\times 0.5) = 0.25 \qquad\text{max occurs when $l=0$, hence arrow from $0.25$ to $1$}\\
& \\
\nu_2(B) &= P(X_2=H\mid \pi_2=B)\max_{l\in\{0,F,B\}} \{\nu_1(l)P(\pi_2=B\mid\pi_1=l)\} \\
&= 0.9\times (1\times 0.5) = 0.45 \qquad\text{max occurs when $l=0$, hence arrow from $0.45$ to $1$}\\
\end{align}

These three values form column $2$ of the result table.

\begin{align}
& \\
\nu_3(0) &= P(X_3=H\mid \pi_3=0)\max_{l\in\{0,F,B\}} \{\nu_2(l)P(\pi_3=0\mid\pi_2=l)\} \\
&= 0 \\
& \\
\nu_3(F) &= P(X_3=H\mid \pi_3=F)\max_{l\in\{0,F,B\}} \{\nu_2(l)P(\pi_3=F\mid\pi_2=l)\} \\
&= 0.5\times (0.45\times 0.9) = 0.2025 \qquad\text{max occurs when $l=B$, hence arrow from $0.2025$ to $0.45$}\\
& \\
\nu_3(B) &= P(X_3=H\mid \pi_3=B)\max_{l\in\{0,F,B\}} \{\nu_2(l)P(\pi_3=B\mid\pi_2=l)\} \\
&= 0.9\times (0.45\times 0.1) = 0.0405 \qquad\text{max occurs when $l=B$, hence arrow from $0.0405$ to $0.45$}\\
\end{align}

These three values form column $3$ of the result table.

The maximum of the column $3$ values is $\nu_3(F)=0.2025$. Following the arrows for that value we get the most probable sequence, namely $0-B-F$.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure I understand the notation, but here's the way I would approach it:  we look at the list of all $2$-toss scenarios.  Restrict to those in which $HH$ is observed and compute the probabilities of each.

Case I:  Start with $B$.
Then you get that first $H$ with probability $.9$

Case $B-B$  you stay with coin $B$, probability $.1$
Then you get the second $H$ with probability $.9$.

Hence Case $B-B$ has probability $.9*.1*.9=\fbox {.081}$

Case $B-F$  you switch to coin $F$, probability $.9$
Then you get the second $H$ with probability $.5.

Hence Case $B-F$ has probability $.9*.9*.5=\fbox {.405}$

Case II:  You start with $F$  Then you get that first $H$ with probability $.5$

Case $F-F$  you stay with coin $F$, probability $.9$
Then you get the second $H$ with probability $.5$.

Hence Case $F-F$ has probability $.5*.9*.5=\fbox {.225}$

Case $F-B$  you switch to coin $B$, probability $.1$
Then you get the second $H$ with probability $.9$.

Hence Case $F-B$ has probability $.5*.1*.9=\fbox {.045}$

Visibly, the case $B-F$ is by far the most probable (it takes up $53.57\%$ of the scenarios in which we observe $HH$.

Note: as mentioned in the comments, if you imagine that the decision to start with $B$ or $F$ is itself probabilistic (probability $\frac 12$ for each), then each of these probabilities should be divided by $2$...that matches the $.2025$ in the table.  I don't understand the other values in that table.

Comment: Sorry, the whole point of Viterbi is that you don't have to go case by case. Imagine you observed a sequence of 500 H's and T's. This is a simplified example to illustrate how you would use Viterbi algorithm but in practice you have larger sets of observations....

Comment: Ah, well then I don't know...can't do it now but later I'll read up on the method.